# Website responsive issue on android mobiles

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design

This is my Client website [Click here](http://healingblendsglobal.net/), it is responsive on all screen which work good on desktop all browsers, Ipad all browsers but i am facing issue on android mobile browser like Chrome and Firefox.

I have one other browser on mobile which is provided by Asus default browser, website working responsive perfect on that..

I tested on multiple Android devices facing responsive issue.

Yes there is viewport meta tag already there

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.666667, maximum-scale=0.666667, user-scalable=0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Any help will be appreciate..

Comment: What is the issue?  What is happening that you don't want to happen? Looks great on Samsung S5 with Chrome browser

Comment: I normally use this for my viewport tag: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

Comment: Hey Deebs, thanks for respond it's really going some crazy stuff here, it was not working fine on my mobile browser chrome or firefox.. now i see it working fine..  still same issue with my other mobile.  Do you find same issue before it is a wordpress website.. No cache plugin there still things make me crazy whole day :)

Comment: @deebs  Do you see something simillar like this  on mobile  http://prnt.sc/b3nwt5   please check